# undefined method `round' for nil:NilClass in action index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am a new rails am trying to use Rating Star in action index page but i get this errors

```
def index
  @listings = Listing.all.order("created_at desc")
end

def show
  impressionist(@listing, nil, { unique: [:session_hash] })
  @reviews =  @listing.reviews.order("created_at DESC")
  unless @reviews.present?
    @avg_review = 0
  else
    @avg_review = @reviews.average(:rating).present? ? @reviews.average(:rating).round(2) : 0
  end
end
```

HAML CODE in action INDEX Page

```
.geodir-category-options.fl-wrap
  .listing-rating.card-popup-rainingvis.star-rating{"data-score" => "#{listing.reviews.average(:rating).round(2)}"}
    %span{style: "float:right"}
      =listing.reviews.count
```

Comment: listing.reviews.average(:rating) is giving a nil value, you need to figure out why

Comment: @kh deep, you are rounding of nil value in your view. Check my answer explained below.

Comment: Please post your error with clarity in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your index.html.haml you should also filter as what you have done in your method show in your controller, so instead of:

```
listing.reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
```

It should be:

```
listing.reviews.average(:rating).present? ? listing.reviews.average(:rating).round(2) : 0
```

Full code:

```
.geodir-category-options.fl-wrap
  .listing-rating.card-popup-rainingvis.star-rating{"data-score" => "#{listing.reviews.average(:rating).present? ? listing.reviews.average(:rating).round(2) : 0}"}
    %span{style: "float:right"}
      =listing.reviews.count
```